# Why website is not accessible on aws while using curl?

Tags: curl, amazon-web-services, connection, port

I am trying to access this website [link](http://www.flipkart.com/) on AWS using curl.

curl [link](http://www.flipkart.com/).

But getting this error -

`curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.flipkart.com port 443: Connection timed out`

I have tried on multiple instances but getting same error. Something to do with the website or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: From outside AWS, I'm getting Moved permanently response. Did you try the same command on a machine outside AWS?

Comment: Yeah its working on local machine

Comment: @NikhilParmar : I am also facing the same issue. Were you able to find a workaround?

Comment: @mandeep_m91 running on a local machine all my scripts

Comment: @NikhilParmar I see. That works fine if you are running the script in batch. That solves half of my problem. I am looking for a realtime solution as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess the owners/operators of that website are blocking incoming http(s) from the ec2 address range - either with their firewall or security group(s). Not the first time I have seen that. Some folks use ec2 instances for nefarious purposes, so its not inconcievable that after being attacked/ddos from an ec2 instance address range, they just blocked them. By and large, regular ec2 instance wouldn't be used by 'regular' users, so blocking the entire range probably wouldn't affect most regular users from using the site as intended.

FYI: I also cannot access the website.

Comment: Yeah I also though so!!